# Can't fetch user chats from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch user chats from firebase firestore but all I can see on the chat screen is a circular progress indicator, Can anyone help me with that plz?

```
         Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getChatRoomMessages(chatRoomId) async {
        return FireStore.collection("ChatRooms")
            .doc(chatRoomId)
            .collection("chat")
            .orderBy("ts", descending: true)
            .snapshots();
      }
    
      Widget chatMessages() {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: messageStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot ds =
                          snapshot.data?.docs[index] as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
                      return Text(ds["message"]);
                    })
                : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        );
      }
    
      getandSetMessages() async {
        messageStream = await getChatRoomMessages(chatRoomID);
        setState(() {});
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        getandSetMessages();
        super.initState();
      }
```

This is where am implementing it in scaffold body ->

```
    body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              chatMessages(),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Container(
```

Comment: Before this line `return snapshot.hasData`, please add this `if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);return Text('Something went wrong);` and check if it prints anything. Also confirm that at least 1 document in the `chat` sub collection contains the value `ts`

Comment: Then it shows the following ERROR -

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string
E/flutter ( 8032): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
E/flutter ( 8032): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter ( 8032): #2      _JsonCollectionReference.doc

Comment: This means that `chatRoomId` is an empty string. `chatRoomId` should not be an empty string.

Comment: i fixed the chatroomID part and now it's not null anymore and that error is solved but still i cant see any of my messages in the chat screen , Note that now the circular progress indicator is also not showing.

Comment: `getChatRoomMessages()` returns a `Stream`, not a `Future`. You do not need to await it or call it in initState. You can use it directly in the `StreamBuilder`. Replace this line `stream: messageStream,` with `stream: FireStore.collection("ChatRooms").doc(chatRoomId).collection("chat").orderBy("ts", descending: true).snapshots(),`.

Comment: tried it , same problem

Comment: Maybe, firebase is not fetching any data. Before `ListView.builder` can you print `snapshot.data?.docs.length` and let me know.

Comment: It shows this - 
I/flutter ( 3676): null
I/flutter ( 3676): null
I/flutter ( 3676): 0

Comment: Alright, 0 means the query is not fetching any document. So, there are no documents in this path "ChatRooms/$chatRoomId/chat" that contains the property "ts". Check your spellings and if the document has the property ts.

Comment: Oh, I resolved the issue, there was a typo problem, Anyways Thank you so much for the great help